# get absolute path in jsp c:forward tag

Tags: jsp, path, forward

How to modify this code to avoid `../../` ?

```
<jsp:forward page="../../errors/error404.jsp" />
```

May be there is some way like this?

```
<jsp:forward page="${???}/errors/error404.jsp" />
```

Comment: Try please ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt post your answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try use it

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

or

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `contextPath` of the application. This is available from the current `HttpServletRequest` instance. To access to it from JSP in form of EL, use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`